# sed to execute a command as replacement with substitution pattern as argument

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I am trying to replace time in a log file by:

```
cat mlog.log | sed -e "s/^[0-9\.]*/\$(date -d @&)/"
```

Why it always first execute `$(date -d $&)` but not doing replacement at first and then execute command?

I thought it would be like:

```
date -d @121223232
```

Log look like this:

```
1428688532.169   peerdiff 2
1428688534.269   peerdiff 1
```

Comment: sorry - \$ was misprint. i'm tryed withoun it before

Answer (score 1):

If mlog.log is space separated:

```
cat mlog.log |perl -a  -ne  'chomp($F[0]=`date -d \@$F[0] +%FT%T`); print join(" ",@F)."\n"'
```

If mlog.log is tab separated:

```
cat mlog.log |perl -a -F"\t" -ne  'chomp($F[0]=`date -d \@$F[0] +%FT%T`); print join("\t",@F)."\n"'
```

Comment: thx! I wrote more full script using your script - cat mlog.log | perl -an -F"\n" -e 'if($F[0] =~ /^[0-9\.]{8,}/){my @a=split(/^([0-9\.]{8,})(.*)/, $F[0]); chomp($a[1]=`date -d \@$a[1] +"%F %T"`); print $a[1].$a[2]} else { print $F[0]} print "\n"'

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works like this is how the shell works. First it starts to interpret everything what it can. I.e. it interprets what is in " quotes. It does not interpret what is in ' quotes. Try to compare `echo "$(date)"` with `echo '$(date)'`. If you want to do what you want you must use another approach, for instance use :

```
awk '{ system("echo `date -d @"$1"` "$2" "$3);}' < mlog.log
```

I.e. make awk split the file into columns and execute system command that you feed with columns as needed. You can not use sed the same way because sed s command has no capability to call the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

[GNU sed has the "**e**" command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands) which:

> pipe input from a shell command into pattern space

For your log:

```
cat mlog.log | sed -r 's/^([0-9\.]+)/echo `date -d @\1`/e'
2015-04-10T19:55:32+02:00 peerdiff 2
2015-04-10T19:55:34+02:00 peerdiff 1
```